# Is there any method that i can call on SecondActivity to add a new item on Arraylist on FirstActivity.Fragment that has Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

Hi im currently building my First android app and i have a problem that i cant solve this past 3 days. so i have MainActivity and on it there is a Fragment with Recyclerview and ArrayList< Item > **listOfItem**, on this Fragment there is a Floating button that when i click it will take me to SecondActivity there is a edit text on this SecondaryActivity that i have to fill then i will pass the data back to **listOfItem**.My problem is what method can i call on SecondActivity to create/add an **listOfItem** when i go back to MainActivity Fragment? I dont want to make Adapter and **listOfItem** to be static. Is there a way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You can achieve this by using Shared Preference.

What you need to do is just save that Edit Text data to Model(POJO), save that Model to Preference and in your Main Activity - Fragment on Resume method show updated data from that Preference.

Yeah here you need to take care of

**The fragments onResume() or onPause() will be called only when the Activities onResume() or onPause() is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity.**

Answer (score 0):

For more convient and efficient handling of data from any activity or fragement to any activity or fragment, you can use Event Bus.. Here is link where you will get the details information:  https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: thanks for this, iwill check how the eventbus work on android.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to start the second `Activity` for result.

`startActivityForResult(ActivityBIntent)`

Then checking the result overriding

`onActivityResult()` on the first activity and updating your list/adapter from it

Comment: Thank, will check this out